text tag is not rendering in flutter
In my flutter app, I receive a svg content as String from server. when I run my app in desktop size it is shown correctly. But when app is run in mobile size it does not displayed. can anyone help me? For example this
<svg width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <text x='45' y='150' font-family='Roboto' font-size='19' font-weight='bold' fill='#C3CEDA' text-anchor='middle' dominant-baseline='middle'>Ma</text>
</svg> 


I found the reason. it was because of locale. in mobile size, I used  Locale("fa", "IR"). after commenting that, it solved :)

The main reason is rtl direction
